# TCP connection to printer via mobile application

Tags: c#, sockets, mobile, printing, tcp

I want to send code to the mobile label printer via mobile application.
I have to do this with TCP connection.
While tcp connection and printing is OK with the windows desktop application,
It just does nothing with the mobile application.
Once I click the connect button it connects to the printer and sends the text without problem
but the printer does not respond!

Appreciate any suggestion

Here is the code

```
private static NetworkStream stream;
private static TcpClient client;
if (client == null)
{
    client = new TcpClient();
    int port = int.Parse(strPort);
    client.Connect(server, port);
}
stream = client.GetStream();
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1251")); 
writer.AutoFlush = false;
writer.Write(Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1251").GetBytes(message).Length); 
writer.Write(message);
writer.Flush();
```

Comment: what is the exact protocol that it expects? the reason I ask is that `Write(int)` followed by `Write(string)` looks pretty ambiguous; that is just "3abc" etc... which doesn't look right (let's hope the message doesn't start with a number!). I would expect it to either have a line-feed after the 3, or for the 3 to be a binary encoding of the length. Btw, `GetByteCount(message)` would be cheaper than `GetBytes(message).Length`. In any networking problem, the first step is to log what you sent. Not what you *thought* you were sending - but what you *actually sent*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, as you have mentioned above: once I removed sending length info it printed the label without problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thought:
Is it possible that the printer requires a delimiter between the messages? How does the printer know where the expected length ends and where the actual message begins?

For example, if the string to print is `12345`, how does the printer know from the TCP message `512345` whether to expect 5 characters or 51 or 512, etc.?

Also I think that it is possible that `Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1251").GetBytes(message).Length` delivers a number different from the number of characters within `message`, if `message` is not in encoding `Windows-1251`.

What you'd have to do is:

1. Convert `message` to a byte array
2. Determine length from that and send byte array

Sample:

```
// Convert message to byte array in Windows 1251 encoding
// Get a byte array that contains the length of messageBytes as string
byte[] messageBytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1251").GetBytes(message);
byte[] messageBytesLengthBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageBytes.Length.ToString());

stream = client.GetStream();
stream.Write(messageBytesLengthBuffer, 0, messageBytesLengthBuffer.Length);
stream.Write(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length);
```

Finally (!), you should really look into closing the resources you open up!

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, what I'm sending to the printer is script for the printer which printer can interpret and print label, I have tried your suggestion but it responds same as before, it debugs without problem but printer does not print label!

Comment: Can you describe the protocol?

Comment: @kubilaybayraktar this just sounds like a protocol error - i.e. you aren't sending what it wants. You need to read the documentation to see what it wants...

Comment: Once I removed this line , the problem is solved: stream.Write(messageBytesLengthBuffer, 0, messageBytesLengthBuffer.Length);